# Magento widget(product_new) Override

Tags: php, magento

I wanted to add category filter to product_new widget in Magento 1.7. 
I have tried the following.

1.Module declaration.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <module_name>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </module_name>
    </modules> </config>
```

2.Added following to config.xml

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <module_name>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </module_name>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_new>Module_Name_Block_Product_New</product_new>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>    
    </global>    
</config>
```

3. Override product new class

```
class Module_Name_Block_Product_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
{

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products and applied page limits.
     *
     * return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
      $todayStartOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('00:00:00')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $todayEndOfDayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()
            ->setTime('23:59:59')
            ->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());


        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate),
                1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
            ), 'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                array(
                    array('attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                    array('attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
                    )
              )
            //->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')

            ->setPageSize($this->getProductsCount())
            ->setCurPage(1);

            if($categoryId=$this->getData('category_id')){
                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
                $collection->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSort('position','asc');
            }            
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc');
        $this->setProductCollection($collection);

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();      

    }
 }
```

4. After this, When i call new product widget in HOME CMS page its give me all new product from all the category, in short my new class in not in effect and still the core classes are called. Below is the widget block.

```
 {{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" products_count="9"  category_id="124"   template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Can anyone please guide me what changes i should do in order to make my class effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is now right:

```
   <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_new>Module_Name_Block_Product_New</product_new>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

It should be

```
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_widget_new>Module_Name_Block_Product_New</product_widget_new>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
```

And you class declaration should be:

```
class Module_Name_Block_Product_New extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New
```

What you did in your code is to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` block but you use in the homepage this one `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New`.
I know you will say that `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Widget_New` already extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New` but even if you've overwritten this last one, the widget block still extends the original one.

Comment: Thanks Marius.. It worked :) i can see my new block name after enebling hints. But my __beforeToHtml() function is not getting override. Category filter is still not getting applied.. is it because it protected function ??

Comment: rewrite that _beforeToHtml function in your new block also: `Module_Name_Block_Product_New`

Comment: I have re-written _beforeHTML in my new block Module_Name_Block_Product_New , But its not still using core's _beforeHTML function. Any idea about this? .. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its Done.. I just changed the return type from parent::_beforeHTML() to $this. Thanks for your help Marius.